# TCPDF - HTML table align right inside writeHTMLCell does not work

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I create a table with HTML to be inserted into TCPDF::writeHTMLCell with this format. The table only contains image.

```
$html_table ='<table align="right" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="10%" align="center">
            <img src="http://localhost/img1.png" width="40" height="40" />
        </td>
        <td width="10%" align="center">
            <img src="http://localhost/img2.png" width="40" height="40" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="10%" align="center">
            <img src="http://localhost/img3.png" width="40" height="40" />
        </td>
        <td width="10%" align="center">
            <img src="http://localhost/img4.png" width="40" height="40" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>';
```

Here's the TCPDF code to create HTMLCell

```
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(100, '', '', $pdf->getY(), $html_table, 1, 0, 0, false, 'R', false);
```

Even thought the HTML can show the table at the right side of page, TCPDF only shows this table at the left side inside the cell.

What is the right code to put the table in align right, put in the right side of the HTMLCell ?